# jquery-ui autoOpen: false does not allow dialog to stay open after event trigger

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, modal-dialog

When I include the autoOpen: False, line to my script, and click the button with the id="opener", the dialog flashes open for a part of a second and then closes.  The script is:

```
  <script>
     $( "#dialog" ).dialog({
         autoOpen: false,
         modal: true,
         width: 500,
      dialogClass: "dlg-no-title",
       buttons: [
         {
           text: "OK",
           click: function() {
             $( this ).dialog( "close" );
           }
         }
       ]
     });
     $( "#opener" ).click(function() {
       $( "#dialog" ).dialog( "open" );
     });
  </script>
```

It looks to me to be the same as every sample I've found, but I've obviously overlooked something. It happens in both Safari and Chrome.

Comment: [Can you set up an example of it?](http://jsfiddle.net/SX4JV/)

Comment: OK, the problem is occurring because the whole page is a form wrapped inside <form></form> tags.The intent was to have the dialog offer some optional form data fields that would be submitted with the form data in the rest of the page.  Is there something else I can do to achieve this result?

Comment: That actually doesn't explain your problem completely. Perhaps, you forgot to add a `type="button"` somewhere considering everything is wrapped in a `<form/>`